# INVALID_ARGUMENT error with Google Analytics Reporting API

Tags: api, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to do a request to the [userActivity.search](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/userActivity/search) method,

this is the payload that I'm trying to do:

```
{
  "viewId": "<VIEW ID>",
  "dateRange": {
    "startDate": "7daysAgo",
    "endDate": "today"
  },
  "user": {
    "type": "CLIENT_ID",
    "userId": "<USER ID>"
  }
}
```

But I'm stuck getting this error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "CLIENT_ID: <ID> not found.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

The ClientId I get previously at other GA endpoint that list the ClientIds that I need to get more details.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: check the userid you are sending are you sure its a user?

Comment: you got the solution?